# Problem of General topology (Schaum)

Tags: general-topology

Let $\tau=\{U \subseteq \mathbb{Z}_+ :$ if $n \in U \implies$ all divisor of $n $ is in $U \}$.

Let $f: (\mathbb{Z}_+,\tau) \to (\mathbb{Z}_+,\tau)$. Prove: $f$ is continuous $\leftrightarrow$ if $m|n $ then  $ f(m) | f(n)$.

$(\leftarrow)$ Let $n \in U$ (open) and let $m \in \mathbb{Z}_+$ such that $m|n$.

I want to prove that $m \in f^{-1} (U)$. We know that  $f(n) \in U$ and $f(m)|f(n)$. Since  $U$ is open , then $f(m) \in U$.  Hence $m \in f^{-1} (U)$

$(\rightarrow)$  ???

Comment: What do you mean by $(Z_+,\tau)$?

Comment: @GregoryGrant it's the space with the topology on it.

Comment: Oh I see, $\tau$ is the topology on $\mathbb Z_+$.  Got it.

Comment: That's a neat topology, I never ran into that one before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that there exists an $n $ such that the implication $m\mid n\implies f (m)\mid f (n) $ does not hold. Then we find an $m $ such that $m\mid n $ but $f (m)\not\mid f (n) $. Now choose $U\in\tau $ to contain only the divisors of $f (n) $. Then $n\in f^{-1}(U) $ but $m\notin f^{-1}(U) $, so $f^{-1}(U)\notin\tau$, completing the proof of the desired implication.

Comment: I think the direct proof of this result is a bit cleaner.

Comment: @Gregory Grant I must agree, however it is always nice to look at it from "both sides".

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $f$ is continuous and $m|n$.  Let $U$ be the set of $a$ such that $a|f(n)$.  Then $U$ is open and $f(n)\in U$.  Thus $n\in f^{-1}(U)$ which is also open.  Thus since $m|n$, $m\in f^{-1}(U)$. Thus $f(m)\in U$.  Thus $f(m)|f(n)$.